# JQuery - capturing page load and unload from iframe when outer page doesn't change

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm working on a site that has an outer menu, with inner content in an iframe.  On one new iframe I'm making I would like to run some code to change the parent page title when the page is fully done loading (using $(window.parent).load).  However, the way the framework is written, when you navigate through the menu to a new "page" the main page does not reload - it just changes the iframe content.

So: the title set works when I go directly to the new page.  If I'm on another page and then navigate to the new page, the title does not get set.  If I then reload the page, it does.  So I'm assuming that when the iframe is changed without a reload, there is no signal that the parent is done when the new iframe is done, so that "load" never triggers.

I do need that code to run when the whole page is done loading, though - it's not enough to run just when the iframe is done loading because then the outer page sets the title after the iframe finishes loading, and overwrites my change.

Is there any way to force my code in the iframe to be the last thing to run, whether or not the outer page is getting reloaded?

The other half of this is that another thing I'm doing in this iframe is hiding an element on the parent.  That works fine, but when I navigate away, I need the element to come back.  And again, if the parent isn't reloading, then the element stays hidden.  I was hoping I could unhide on unload, but just like the load above, unload code doesn't seem to be triggering if the outer page isn't reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're in a pickle.
First and foremost, I will assume both URLs (parent and child) reside on the same domain — otherwise you're going to open yourself up to a whole other can of worms.

If they do reside on the same domain... then:
You can't listen to the `load` event of a parent page anyway. So don't bother going down that rabbit hole.

Instead, what you'll want to do is use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). This allows you to communicate between both frames effectively.

In your parent, set up your listener before loading your iframe.

```
window.addEventListener("message", function (ev) {
  if (ev.origin !== "http://my-website.org") return;
  console.log("message is", ev.data)
  document.title = ev.data
}, false)
```

and within your iframe's script:

```
window.postMessage("yo there", "http://my-website.org")
```

Experiment with that and hopefully you'll get things sorted out the way you need. [Here is also a good tutorial](http://davidwalsh.name/window-postmessage) on it.

Comment: They are on the same domain, yes.  Unfortunately I'm not sure I can add the code that seems to be required to the parent pages (it's Microsoft CRM, so I can't just get in and easily make code changes...hence the need to deal with internal iframes for custom stuff).  I'd originally assumed I couldn't use postMessage because of that, but I'll give it a further poke to confirm.